# update table column using two subset query

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am using one query where i have to update one column for that i have two subset of query which is below:

```html
select a.AuthorId as 'Source_Author',b.AuthorId as 'Target_Author' from (
select d.documentnodeid,AuthorId from wv_blogdata
inner join CMS_Document d on wv_blogdata.BlogDataID = d.DocumentForeignKeyValue
Where DocumentCulture ='en-US') a
INNER JOIN
(select d.documentnodeid,AuthorId from wv_blogdata
inner join CMS_Document d on wv_blogdata.BlogDataID = d.DocumentForeignKeyValue
Where DocumentCulture ='de-DE') b
ON a.documentnodeid =b.documentnodeid
```

using this query i have value like below:
[image: sql result]

Now i have to update target author with source author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common table expression

```
;WITH cteUpdate
AS(
    select a.AuthorId as 'Source_Author',b.AuthorId as 'Target_Author' 
    FROM
    (
            SELECT d.documentnodeid,AuthorId from wv_blogdata
            INNER join CMS_Document d on wv_blogdata.BlogDataID = d.DocumentForeignKeyValue
            WHERE DocumentCulture ='en-US'
    ) a
    INNER JOIN
    (       SELECT d.documentnodeid,AuthorId from wv_blogdata
            INNER join CMS_Document d on wv_blogdata.BlogDataID = d.DocumentForeignKeyValue
            WHERE DocumentCulture ='de-DE'
    ) b
    ON a.documentnodeid =b.documentnodeid
)
UPDATE
    cteUpdate
SET
    cteUpdate.Target_Author = cteUpdate.Source_Author
```

Comment: Hey it's works as i has expected. Thanks Mountaineer. I am marking this as answer.